# Can't launch to browser from notepad++ anymore

Tags: xml, notepad++, launch

I have encountered a very annoying and irritating problem when I updated to the latest version of Notepad++.

I can't seem to launch to a browser or any program what so ever anymore from the RUN window. The RUN window itself is completely empty and doesn't show any LAUNCH commands any more.

I am not sure what happened but It's tearing me to shreds because I use the function all the freaking time for direct e-mail previewing.

I tried replacing and rewriting the "shortcuts.xml" but to no avail.

RUN menu looks like this now:

[image]

Comment: what keeps you from downgrading till the problem got fixed ? I think notepad++ has a mailing list, perhaps you should report the problem there because others might have the same problem

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I did a downgrade to try and solve it, but perhaps I should downgrade to a much older version. 

Still I would like this very basic function to work properly, so I hope someone can still assist me with this

Comment: "Latest version" is a meaningless term. Which version specifically, from the menu => **?** => **About Notepad++** command? The run menu is built from the `<UserDefinedCommands>` section of the `shortcuts.xml` file (at `C:\Users\adrian\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml` on my computer). Perhaps that file has been corrupted.

Comment: I fixed the file and It seems to be working again, thank you for your response. I would not have thought of this myself.